# How to get the constructed / executed query from the DataStax Cassandra driver?

Tags: python, datastax, cassandra-driver

I'm using the DataStax Cassandra driver. After the following (example) code:

```
foo_query = 'SELECT * FROM foo_column_family where bar = %(bar_id)s'

    try:
        foos = cassandra_session.execute(foo_query, {'bar_id': bar_id})
        logger.info('Executed query: {}'.format(not_sure_what_goes_in_here())
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Error executing Cassandra query: %s'.format(e))
        raise e
```

I'd like to have logged the query I'd just `execute()`d.  I had already tried using `foo_query.get_all_query_traces())` where the `not_sure` part is. However, I'm only seeing an empty array in there. Is there some switch for enabling query traces? I couldn't find anything by scanning the [documentation index](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/genindex.html).